# How to make a ChannelSet login() secure in flex

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

i recently had a look to the tutorial for custom authentication within a flex application. The login is managed by getting the ChannelSet from a RemoteObject:

```
private function creationCompleteHandler():void {
            if (cs == null)
                cs = ServerConfig.getChannelSet(remoteObject.destination);                    
        }

// Login and handle authentication success or failure. 
private function ROLogin():void {
            // Make sure that the user is not already logged in.
            if (cs.authenticated == false) {
                token = cs.login("sampleuser", "samplepassword");
                // Add result and fault handlers.
                token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(LoginResultEvent, LoginFaultEvent));
            }
        }
```

After that the channlset can be used with the login command of ChannelSet. How can i insure that this is using a secure connection? I know that there is a amf channel and a secure amf channel. But how to tell to provide the credentials in a secure connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a ChannelSet is defined with a group of channels that define a fail-over strategy, rather than as part of a secure/non-secure segmentation.

Mixing encrypted & non-encrypted channels in the same channelset doesn't really make sense.

When a channelSet has multiple channels defined, the Flex client will attempt to connect on the first, and gracefully fail through to the next, and the next until a connection is established, or all channels are exhausted.

If you want to have both secure & non-secure channels defined, you would typcially define two channelsets - one for each:

```
<s:ChannelSet id="channelSet">
   <s:AMFChannel url="http://myserver:8080/myapp/messagebroker/amf" />
</s:ChannelSet>
<s:ChannelSet id="encryptedChannelSet">
   <s:SecureAMFChannel url="https://myserver:8080/myapp/messagebroker/amf" />
</s:ChannelSet>

public function logon():void
{
     // Credentials are passed via https
     encryptedChannelSet.login("username","password");
}
```

What *isn't* clear from the documentation is that assuming that both `channelSet` and `encryptedChannelSet` are part of the same messageBroker, the authentication state and user credentials are available across both channelSets.

Ie., although the client code suggests that credentials are supplied to only a single ChannelSet, on the server side, the `FlexContext` is what holds the authentication state, which is associated with the browser session, not a specific channel or channelSet.

So, after authenticating the `encryptedChannelSet`, destinations which are exposed to the `channelSet` which are secured and require user credentials are now accessible.

Comment: But how secure is the login() command? Is it encrypted in there for transmission?

Comment: Assuming that you use the https:// connection, then it's as secure as any other SSL traffic - ie., secure enough.  You can encrypt the password before sending it, though if the call is going over https:// it's not required.